# Quotients of $p$-adic completion

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $p \in R$. Consider the $p$-adic completion $\widehat{R} := \varprojlim_{n} \, R/p^n$.

When do we have $\widehat{R}/p^n \widehat{R} \cong R/p^n R$?

For fixed $n$ there are natural maps of $R$-algebras $R/p^n \to \widehat{R}/p^n \widehat{R} \to R/p^n$ whose composition is the identity of $R/p^n$. But I don't know why or if the other composition is the identity of $\widehat{R}/p^n \widehat{R}$.

If $R$ is noetherian, it seems to be true, by general results of completions: $\widehat{R}/p^n \widehat{R}  = \widehat{R} \otimes_R R/p^n R = \widehat{R/p^n R} = R/p^n R$.

In general, it suffices to treat the case $n=1$. In fact, this implies $\widehat{R} = R + p \widehat{R}$ and then by induction $\widehat{R} = R + p^n \widehat{R}$ for all $n \geq 1$, i.e. $R/p^n \to \widehat{R}/p^n \widehat{R}$ is surjective.

For $n=1$ we have to show that $\widehat{R}/p \widehat{R} \to R/p$ is injective. But I haven't been able to prove this. At least when $p$ is regular there are no problems. Here is an elementary reformulation of the claim:

> Given a sequence of elements $x_n \in p R$ such that $x_{n+1} \equiv x_n \bmod p^n$, why is there is a sequence of elements $y_n \in R$ such that $x_n \equiv p y_n \bmod p^n$ and $y_{n+1} \equiv y_n \bmod p^n$?

Comment: That limit *is* the inverse limit, right?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's always the case that $\widehat{R}/p^n \widehat{R} = R/p^n R$.

To see this, recall that any element of $\widehat{R}$ can be written as a
sum $\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty} p^i r_i,$ where $r_i \in R$ (or, more precisely,
is in the image of $R$ in $\widehat{R}$).  Thus we see that
$\widehat{R} = \text{im}(R) + p^n \widehat{R},$ and so the natural map
$R/p^n \to \widehat{R}/p^n \widehat{R}$ is surjective.

Combined with what you already know, this completes the proof.

[I think this extends to the completion w.r.t. any finitely generated ideal.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! "recall ... " I only know this when $R$ is a PID with prime element $p$. I try to prove it in the general setting ...

Comment: Dear Martin, You should be able to prove it using the  "telescoping trick" for passing between convergent series and convergent sequences in the non-archimedean setting.  Best wishes,

Comment: Everything boils down to $\ker(\widehat{R} \to R/pR) = p \widehat{R}$, but I've already spend some time to prove this, without success. It should be really elementary, *blush*

Comment: Meanwhile I've found a proof, but it's quite long ... wonder if there is an easy argument.